# Eliminate empty strings from output string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am reading data from an HTML table and then sending the results to server based on whether a checkbox is checked.  The problem is when you read the td with the checkbox input it returns an empty string, which I would like to eliminate.  Here's some code:

```
addToPlan : function(){
    var deleteSQL = '';
    deleteSQL = $('#user').val() + '#' + $('#pass').val() + '# \r';
    $('tr').has(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    //+var selected = $('tr').has(':checkbox:checked').find('td').each(function(){

        deleteSQL +='"'
        deleteSQL += $(this).text()
        deleteSQL += '",';

    });
    deleteSQL +='\r';
    });
    console.log(deleteSQL);
    // use this to get things to be deleted 
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'deleteSites.jsp',
        data : {q : deleteSQL},

    });
```

So what I want is a bunch of comma separated values further delimited by \r, but I want to skip the td /td in $.this that has a checkbox

Current output looks like this:

```
Query= ## 
"192.168.0.101","ria","","Ping",
"192.168.0.101","ria","","Ping",
```

Note the offending empty strings.

Comment: If you are building SQL statements on the client that are going to be executed on the server, prepare to be hacked!

Comment: Have you ever heard of `if` statements? Just test whether the string is empty, and skip over the code that adds to the variable.

Comment: Why build this data into, in essence, a CSV?  Why not put it into a multidimensional array and then serialize to JSON for transmittal?  Much easier to work with on both ends.

Comment: Yes thank you. I have heard of this, which of course I tried before asking. I am not very good though. Do you have a sample?

Comment: No, I am not really going to send SQL. Thanks.

Comment: You're deleting "sites" on the front-end ?! Your app must be really secure. Send a parameter to the back-end and write your SQL there. Have you heard about XSS and about the fact that anyone can modify the source file in Firebug (or any other tool) and kill/hack the functionality of your code ?!

Comment: Thanks all for your thoughtful input. This is not an app, or anywhere near a product that will be generally available. This is a simple UI that is for demonstration of a Java application.  The sever side guys are not at all interested in dealing with the implications of actually putting the product into production with the current UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try eliminating the td with the checkbox from the selection in the first place.

Assign `class="checkbox"` to the `td`, then call `$(this).find('td').not('.checkbox').each(function() {...});`

This way, you'll only be selecting the non-checkbox `td`s

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
deleteSQL.replace(',""','').replace('"",','').replace('""','');
```